# Armazenar campos date do Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Não estou encontrando uma solução para armazenar somente a data, sempre é exigido a hora.

Erro:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value
```

Comment: o seu banco não está como datetime e por isso acontece o erro?

Comment: O formato que você está enviando que é inválido, como você está enviando a data? e poderia colocar o código?

Comment: A ideia é que o usuário digite assim  31-01-2019
E no banco fique assim 2019-01-31

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso via código! se pode postar o código?

Comment: Minha Store $data = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->vencimento_titulo)); $data = $request->all();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo da tabela em que você quer salvar é no formato `DateTime`, naturalmente ele necessita da hora. Para armazenar apenas datas, use `$this->date('campo')` na criação da tabela.

Comment: Já se encontra como date 

$table->date('vencimento_titulo')->nullable();

Comment: @AndréCabral poste um trecho de código da criação da tabela e de como você está salvando para que eu possa te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Minha Store
$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($request->vencimento_titulo));
$data = $request->all();

Comment: Na conversão, além da data, você está colocando `H:i:s`, que é o formato de hora, minuto e segundo. Se você quer converter e salvar a data, eu recomendo que use o `Carbon`, com o seguinte código: `\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->vencimento_titulo)`, presumindo que `vencimento_titulo` esteja no formato dia, mês, ano. Outro detalhe, na sua `model`, adicione o `vencimento_titulo` no `array` `$dates` e tire-o do `$fillable`, [clique aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) e veja a documentação para mais detalhes.

Comment: Não deu certo, assim a ideia é que o usuario digite: 31/12/2019 e o laravel faça a conversão  2019-12-31

Comment: Troque então o formato de `d-m-Y` para `d/m/Y` e me diga o que produz. Depois, você pode usar o `Carbon` para realizar a conversão, depois, você pode converter para `string` e produzir a data no formato desejado para salvar ou simplesmente salvar a instância do `Carbon` que o Laravel já irá reconhecer que é uma data.

Comment: [resolvi]  O problema estava na lógica, obrigado pela paciência

$date = str_replace("/", "-", $request->vencimento_titulo);
$date =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');